# Writing function $f(x,y)$ along a line as the value at a point plus integral of partial derivatives?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose We have a function $f(x,y)$. As an example lets consider $f(x,y)=x^2y^2$

Suppose we know the following

1. The value of the point at a point, $(a,b)$. As an example, consider $(a,b)=(5,1)$
2. The partial derivatives of the function, $f_1$ and $f_2$.

Now suppose we want the value of the function along a line that has $(a,b)$ as an endpoint.

**Question**: Can we write $f(x,y)$ along every point on this line in terms of $f(a,b)$ and $f_1$, and $f_2$?

---

For example, suppose I want the values of $f$ along the line $6-x$ for $x∈ [1,5]$, and suppose we know that $f(5,1)= 25$.

Then can I write $$f(x,6-x) = f(5,1) + \int_x^5 \left(-f_1(x,6-x) + f_2 (x,6-x)\right)dx $$

A quick simulation suggests that this works for $f(x,y)=x^2y^2$ and the line $y=6-x$, **but I don't know if such a result always holds**

**Also** the (-) sign on $f_1$ is important.

- If we instead consider the line $y=x-4, x>4$ then we need a (+) sign. **Is there a way to write the formula regardless the direction we are moving?**

Note: Assume we are considering an $f$ that is continuous and infinitely differentiable. (and at points where the partial derivatives are all defined) If other smoothness conditions are needed to make the result true feel free assume them, but please state what they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a line $y=Mx+c$, we can parametrise points along this line in terms of a new variable $t$ by something like $x=t, y=Mt+c$. Then we can consider $f$ as a function on this line by defining
$$F(t)=f(t,Mt+c)$$

By the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$F(t) -F(t_0) =\int_{t_0}^t F'(t)dt$$

By the multivariable chain rule
$$F'(t)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$

Using this, you get a formula that works for any line, once you fix a parametrisation.

In this case
$$F'(t) = 2(t)(Mt+c)^2(1) + 2(t^2)(Mt+c)(M)$$

and it is the sign of your M that determines the sign in the sum.

Note that this works for any path from $t_0$ to $t$, but the expression for the integral depends explicitly on the parametrisation. Unfortunately, there is no path independent approach that I know of.

(Indeed, if $f$ is not sufficiently smooth, the value of the integral will depend explicitly on the parametrisation, much as in integration of functions with poles in complex analysis)

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you happen to know any references or places I could look for more info on such approaches/parameterizations?

Comment: I can't think of a specific reference, but I'd suggest reading about line integrals and conservative functions in vector calculus, or Cauchy's theorem if complex analysis is something that interests you. Conservative functions are precisely those whose integrals are path independent and there are some nice characterisations of them in certain cases